# How to convert Xls file with formula through PhpExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have an xls file which i was trying to upload using PhpExcel plugin .

My code is like this

```
Excel::load($file_path, function($sheet) {

                $detail = $sheet->get();
                var_dump($detail);
           });
```

Since my file had excel formula the  Plugin is throwing following error

> PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: 10!I9 -> Formula Error: Unexpected ,

My question is how do i remove the formula and then try uploading it ?

Thanks